# C++ write binary file. uchar* data from opencv matrices

Tags: c++, opencv, binary

I have some data, n elements, uchar* data_ptr. How would I write this to a binary file and read it again later?

I tried the following :

```
std::ofstream myFile ("data.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
myFile.write(data_ptr,100);
```

Above won't compile. uchar not being char.

How do I write it. And how to I read it into a memory chunk of uchar* again.

I did the following test:

```
cv::Mat test(10,10,CV_8UC1);
cv::randu(test,0,255);
std::cout << test << std::endl;
assert(test.isContinuous());

std::ofstream myFile1 ("data1.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
myFile1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(test.data),sizeof(uchar)*100);

uchar buf[100];
std::ifstream myFile ("data1.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
myFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), sizeof(buf));
cv::Mat test1(10,10,CV_8UC1,buf);
std::cout << test1 << std::endl;

cv::waitKey();
```

And got the following output:

```
[91, 2, 79, 179, 52, 205, 236, 8, 181, 239;
  26, 248, 207, 218, 45, 183, 158, 101, 102, 18;
  118, 68, 210, 139, 198, 207, 211, 181, 162, 197;
  191, 196, 40, 7, 243, 230, 45, 6, 48, 173;
  242, 125, 175, 90, 63, 90, 22, 112, 221, 167;
  224, 113, 208, 123, 214, 35, 229, 6, 143, 138;
  98, 81, 118, 187, 167, 140, 218, 178, 23, 43;
  133, 154, 150, 76, 101, 8, 38, 238, 84, 47;
  7, 117, 246, 163, 237, 69, 129, 60, 101, 41;
  190, 50, 90, 72, 168, 109, 121, 220, 114, 248]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127, 2, 0, 0;
  32, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 178, 116;
  36, 101, 35, 0, 28, 5, 248, 227, 87, 0;
  43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 205, 18, 246, 118, 251, 10, 251, 118]
```

Clearly the two matrices are not the same. Any comment on where it went wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, don’t use `uchar*`. Use `std::vector<uchar>` or `std::array<uchar>`.

Comment: Its the data representation of opencv matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write, you can simply cast the data to `char*`:

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data_ptr), 100); // writes 100 bytes
```

To read, you need an `istream` and again a cast is required:

```
uchar buf[100];
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), sizeof(buf));
```

Comment: You wrote writes 100bytes. So if my data was of type int32 and there was 100 elements, i would have to write 400 bytes ? or n*sizeof(type).

Comment: Yes, you would just use n*sizeof(type) to get the correct size in bytes.

Comment: @s093294: Yes, `n * sizeof(type)` is the formula. However, you should be aware that if the size is greater than 1 you may have endianness problems if your program runs on multiple platforms. In that case I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: If what has size greater than one ?

Comment: @s093294: if `sizeof(type) > 1`.

Comment: Do not everything have a size larger then 1byte ? And what are the endiannes problem that i should look into.

Comment: the endianess problem is that you may write the file on one platform, and when you read the file on a platform with a different endianess you will not be able to read it correctly. The data will appear to be garbage. When serializing data, whether for disk or the network or anything else, it's good to store values using 'network byte order'.

Comment: I guess i should read up on that, i would like to be able to read my files again on all systems. Is it easy to setup?

Comment: Updated my question with a sample, my writing and reading did not end up with the same data :(

Comment: If i want to write a struct header{ uint records;} at the start of the file. How to i tell the file to start at position sizeof(header) such that there are rooom for the struct when im done writing?

Comment: @bames53 If targeting Unix(ubuntu) Mac and windows, would i run in to problems ?

Comment: @s093294 Most systems running Ubuntu, Mac, and Windows are on x86, so they share the same endianess. Though sometimes Ubuntu and Mac are run on big endian systems like PPC, it may not be often enough anymore that you care to support it.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast your data; `ofstream` is character based. In your case, use `reinterpret_cast<char*>(data_ptr)` and everything will work. When reading, just cast the buffer as well (and use the `read` method of an `ifstream`.)

Comment: Hu? Why would you define a custom operator for uchar*? That won't work, how do you figure out where the uchar stream ends?

Comment: Is the cast operation expensive? I have a huge chunk of data and i am using file.write in a loop where the writing is determined based on a mask array. So should i work on something that can cast the hole data at start or just cast at each write iteration?

Comment: @s093294: The cast has absolutely no runtime cost.

Comment: Thanks. But it does perform better to write a large chunk in one write compared to writing small chunks in a loop still right.

Comment: It's usually faster to do all at once (especially for something like chars, the loop will be the most expensive.) Disk I/O is most likely the same, as the streams have some buffer, so you'r not going to hit the disk for each and every character.